# Cannot create a table with a default value from a sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I'm trying to create a table and I'm getting ORA-00984 'Column not allowed here' message.  It's a very straightforward table.

```
CREATE TABLE all_users
(user_id number DEFAULT user_id_seq.NEXTVAL PRIMARY KEY, 
email_address VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);
```

it keeps kicking me out this error.  Can someone help please?
I also have other tables I'm trying to create as well and am getting the same error.

Comment: You need to use a trigger for using a sequence.  In Oracle 12c+, you can use `generated always as`.

Comment: That syntax is only supported in Oracle 12, not in earlier versions. The name is also a bad choice because there is already a public synonym in Oracle with that name - that will give you lots of trouble.